# How to add specific color to Table row in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm trying to change the color of a row on a table based on a hex value for the row item. I'm basically trying to generate the css on the fly similar to generating a cssLayout like this

```
CssLayout content = new CssLayout( ) {
      @Override
      public String getCss( Component c ) {
        return "background: " + colorCode + ";";
      }
    };
```

Here's the code I'm using now

```
    table.setCellStyleGenerator(
    new Table.CellStyleGenerator( ) {
      public String getStyle( Object itemId, Object propertyId ) {
        return  "green";
      }
    } );
```

But it only works for setting the stylename, so I'd have to have millions of style names to accommodate all the possible hex values for the colors the user wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CSSInject Add-on to add needed style name on the fly.

See https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/cssinject

```
String color = "#CCDDFF";
CSSInject css = new CSSInject(getUI());
css.setStyles("."+color+" { background-color: "+color+"; }");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't want to use an addon and I'm on Vaadin 6.something. I ended up using a CssLayout like in the code I have above, but I'm sure this will be helpful to other people with the same problem.

Comment: Oups sorry, I didn't think about vaadin 6.
The same Add-on is available for 6.3+, with almost the same syntax.  
  
    String color = "#CCDDFF";  
    CSSInject css = new CSSInject();  
    css.setValue("."+color+" { background-color: "+color+"; }");  
    mainLayout.addComponent(css);

Comment: I have the same problem now. Colors are coming from a database. There are no "names" for the colors, and it is not possible to tell how many of them there will be. So I need something to set a concrete rgb color of a table row. Generating arbitrary number of CSS names on the fly (while the main layout is already rendered on the screen) seems inappropiate.

Answer (score 0):

In the existing CSS file you can define the color changes as `background-color: #00ff00;` for the style "green" and return the style green considering your constraints.Have a look [color changes](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/1343446).

Comment: I think this won't help, since hwe would need to have all possible colors by name in the CSS file, since he has not 2-3 colors but instead wishes to (potentially) use all available colors from #000000 to #FFFFFF